# oracle sql count case statements returning sum of all columns

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a query where I am trying to count the number of transactions per day by pers id for each day of the week and I am seeing something I can't figure out. Instead of showing the count per day, I'm getting the sum of the count for all days in each days' column. Here's my script:

```
    Select distinct
    pers.prsid, 

    count(case when trim(to_char(transaction.actdatetime, 'day')) = 'Monday' THEN transaction.rtxnnbr ELSE 0 END) as "Monday",

    count(case when trim(to_char(transaction.actdatetime, 'day')) = 'Tuesday' THEN transaction.rtxnnbr ELSE 0 END) as "Tuesday",

    count(case when trim(to_char(transaction.actdatetime, 'day')) = 'Wednesday' THEN transaction.rtxnnbr ELSE 0 END) as "Wednesday",

    count(case when trim(to_char(transaction.actdatetime, 'day')) = 'Thursday' THEN transaction.rtxnnbr ELSE 0 END) as "Thursday",

    count(case when trim(to_char(transaction.actdatetime, 'day')) = 'Friday' THEN transaction.rtxnnbr ELSE 0 END) as "Friday"

    FROM PERS, TRANSACTION 

    WHERE 
    ((TRANSACTION.POSTDATE between TO_DATE('03-05-2018','MM-DD-YYYY') AND TO_DATE('03-09-2018','MM-DD-YYYY')) 
AND ((TRANSACTION.ORIGPERSNBR = PERS.PERSID(+)))
```

Output:

```
prsid   Monday  Tuesday Wednesday   Thursday    Friday
1050    60      60      60          60          60
1090    66      66      66          66          66
```

What I was expecting to see:

```
prsid   Monday  Tuesday Wednesday   Thursday    Friday
1050    10      15      5           19          11
1090    15      11      20          6           14
```

EDIT: Added the table join that I forgot to copy over

Comment: You appear to be doing a cross join between pers and transaction.

Comment: When you use `COUNT` remove the `ELSE 0` part. Or switch to `SUM(0/1)`

Comment: @DanBracuk sorry, this is just a snippet of the full code. I didn't show the join

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following query:

```
SELECT
    p.prsid, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN TRIM(TO_CHAR(r.actdatetime, 'day')) = 'Monday' THEN t.rtxnnbr ELSE 0 END) AS "Monday",
    SUM(CASE WHEN TRIM(TO_CHAR(t.actdatetime, 'day')) = 'Tuesday' THEN t.rtxnnbr ELSE 0 END) AS "Tuesday",
    SUM(CASE WHEN TRIM(TO_CHAR(t.actdatetime, 'day')) = 'Wednesday' THEN t.rtxnnbr ELSE 0 END) AS "Wednesday",
    SUM(CASE WHEN TRIM(TO_CHAR(t.actdatetime, 'day')) = 'Thursday' THEN t.rtxnnbr ELSE 0 END) AS "Thursday",
    SUM(CASE WHEN TRIM(TO_CHAR(t.actdatetime, 'day')) = 'Friday' THEN t.rtxnnbr ELSE 0 END) as "Friday"
FROM PERS p
INNER JOIN TRANSACTION t
    ON p.TRANS_ID = t.ID
WHERE 
    t.POSTDATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('03-05-2018','MM-DD-YYYY') AND
    TO_DATE('03-09-2018','MM-DD-YYYY'
GROUP BY
    p.prsid
```

The key points are that you likely intended to join the person and transaction tables.  Also, from your case expressions you might have intended to sum the `rtxnnbr` field rather than counting it.  You don't need to use distinct, but rather aggregate by person using `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need a `join` condition:

```
FROM PERS JOIN
     TRANSACTION 
     ON PERS.? = TRANSACTION.?
```

If you always use explicit `JOIN` syntax, you won't have this problem.

As for writing the query, I would go for:

```
SELECT pers.prsid, 
       sum(case when to_char(t.actdatetime, 'DY') = 'MON' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Monday",
       sum(case when to_char(t.actdatetime, 'DY') = 'TUE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Tuesday",
       sum(case when to_char(t.actdatetime, 'DY') = 'WED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Wednesday",
       sum(case when to_char(t.actdatetime, 'DY') = 'THU' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Thursday",
       sum(case when to_char(t.actdatetime, 'DY') = 'FRI' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Friday"
FROM PERS p JOIN
     TRANSACTION t
     ON p.? = t.?  -- probably prsid
WHERE t.POSTDATE >= DATE '2018-03-05' AND
      t.POSTDATE < DATE '2018-03-10'
GROUP BY p.prsid;
```

Notes:

- Use `DATE` constants for, well, date constants.  Also, the `>=` and `<` helps avoid problems -- particularly in a database where the `DATE` data type has a time component and often prints out only using the date.
- Use an explicit `GROUP BY`.  You have an aggregation query.  Be proud and use `GROUP BY`.
- The use of `TRIM()` with the full weekday name is correct.  However, the use of three character abbreviations is simpler.

Comment: Should be a `LEFT JOIN`, there was old Oracle syntax: `PERS.PERSID(+)`

Comment: I only copied a snippet of the full code so I mistakenly left the joins out. The are in there. Thanks for suggesting sum 1/0 also, that's a better way to do it. Same with not using between. It took me a while to realize I was mixing cases ('Fri' not 'FRI'). I added lower() to be safe because I'm lazy.

Answer (score 0):

When you `count` you count all `not null` values and the `ELSE 0` always returns a value.

Either remove it:

```
count(case when trim(to_char(transaction.actdatetime, 'day')) = 'Monday' 
           THEN transaction.rtxnnbr END) as "Monday",
```

or switch to `SUM(0/1)`:

```
SUM(case when trim(to_char(transaction.actdatetime, 'day')) = 'Monday' 
         THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Monday",
```

Comment: sum(0/1) is a great way to handle this and it worked for me.